# Not able to change default font to Optima in android device using jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery, mobile, fonts

I am trying to change default font to "Optima" in android device using query mobile. When i tested , the font is not changing in Android device. But when i test in Crome or Safari, its working.

Can any one have idea how to change font in android device.(other than google fonts solution).

Thanks,
Ravi S Karri.

Answer (score 0):

you need have the CSS to read the font from a local folder in your site, so you need to have the font files in your local folder and then define your font in your CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family:'Optima';
  font-style:normal;
  font-weight:700;
  src: local('Optima'), local('Optima'), url(../font/Optima.woff) format('woff');
}
```

and then use it as you used to use it before:

```
font-family:Optima;
```

Comment: I tried with TFF format with same above already. its not working.

Comment: no, it's better to use woff, ttf, svg. if you can put the others, it's good but not necessary I suppose!